# Terminal velocity on reentry?

Tags: launch, velocity, vertical-landing

I've seen many references to "terminal velocity" on reentry, e.g., prior to a Falcon 9 landing burn.

And I'm confused by this.

Because terminal velocity comes from drag which depends closely on air density and drag coefficient.

And air density increases a lot as the rocket descends. And the drag coefficient changes a lot—and very nonlinearly—as the rocket goes from supersonic to subsonic.

(A Falcon 9 is traveling at hundreds of m/s when the final landing burn begins---right in that transonic region where the drag coefficient is highly nonlinear).

So the force balance on the rocket (before ignition) is:

$$
mg - \frac{1}{2} C_\texttt{D}(v) \rho(h) A v^2 = 0,
$$

or:

$$
v = \sqrt{\left(\frac{2mg}{C_\texttt{D}(v) \rho(h) A}\right)},
$$

where velocity is not a constant, not even approximately, but a variable changing wildly (and nonlinearly) during descent.

Am I not seeing this right?

A parachuter normally jumps from no more than a mile or two above ground at no more than 150 mph, so changes in air density and drag coefficient are small and you can approximate them as constant---meaning it's OK to talk of terminal velocity there.

But a transonic rocket dropping rapidly and wildly in speed and altitude? At best, you can speak of a *variable* terminal speed, it seems? And if it's variable, then what meaning does "terminal" have anymore?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're asking a bit? I don't see an issue with a variable terminal velocity and how it relates to transonic flight. I mean, the speed of sound is dependent on a bunch of variables too, so it's not a fixed number either.

Comment: "Terminal velocity" implies a hard limit on fast you can go. Jump out of a plane and you'll soon hit a max speed and keep going at that max speed. A variable terminal velocity no longer behaves as a limit, so it becomes no different from any other velocity calculated from a force balance.

Comment: Well, you've got your definition mixed up. Terminal velocity is "the constant speed that a freely falling object eventually reaches when the resistance of the medium through which it is falling prevents further acceleration", not some sort of speed limit. Also, it's not like this can't vary. For example, a skydiver jumping from space would have an extremely high terminal velocity high up because there is basically no atmosphere, and as she approaches the surface, her terminal velocity decreases. If the skydiver had a thruster to point upwards, they could simply exceed terminal velocity.

Comment: @user39728 Terminal velocity is the speed at which the force of gravity equals the force of drag. It's not a speed limit - as a spacecraft re-enters the atmosphere, it invariably finds itself going *faster* than terminal velocity for the local atmospheric conditions, which is why aerobraking is a viable means to slow down. You must *decelerate* to terminal velocity, as opposed to a skydiver, who *accelerates* to terminal velocity.

Comment: Sure. I'm not disputing the definition of terminal velocity. I know what it is. My point is that people suggest the rocket eventually settles at a *constant* terminal velocity. But there is no constant terminal velocity, and the rocket will continue to accelerate/decelerate as it drops through the atmosphere before the final landing burn.

Comment: Terminal velocity decreases as the rocket or any other object descends, and it's always approaching terminal velocity rather than exactly at it, but these details usually aren't relevant in contexts where people are talking about terminal velocity. If you need something more accurate, use something more accurate.

Comment: This seems to be a english-language-use quibble you're getting at, but typically, "constant terminal velocity" implies the falling object's velocity follows local terminal velocity (obviously with some delay or similar). Language wise, a roller coaster that is "constantly on the track" is analogous--the coaster still moves in three dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that terminal velocity varies.

For a given vehicle in a given attitude relative to the airstream (i.e. a particular angle of attack), though, it varies only with the air density and therefore primarily by altitude. The $C_D$ varies with airspeed, but it doesn't change very much over the slow subsonic regime of low-altitude terminal velocity, and it changes continuously, so terminal velocity does converge rather than somehow oscillating wildly.

So the meaning, and the exact value, of terminal velocity is always changing, and dependent on context.

For a falling object that's going to hit the ground, the "terminal" part of the term is definitive: it's the terminal, last, final velocity the object has before it hits the ground.

When speaking of a Falcon 9's first stage, "terminal velocity before the landing burn" means exactly that -- the natural falling velocity reached by the stage before the engines fire. It's the terminal (final, last) velocity of the free-falling portion of the flight.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. I just wish we had a better term for that velocity other than "terminal"---which clearly a lot of people casually interpret as a constant (and which I would too if I didn't know better).

Comment: But doesn't the drag coefficient change the fastest as you go from supersonic to subsonic? E.g., http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/journal/134/1341026/image062.jpg

Comment: And air density changes by some 50% in the first 3 km above ground too: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/docs/documents/195/air-altitude-density.png

Comment: So both drag coefficient and air density change very much in the final few km before touch down... That terminal velocity is not even remotely close to constant. It *is* changing very, very rapidly as the rocket descends.

Comment: Ah, I meant to say subsonic, not transonic. Terminal velocity for an empty aluminum can is pretty low.

Comment: Who cares how fast you were going a km ago? What matters is terminal velocity at the instant you light up the engines for the landing burn.

Comment: An example of someone treating terminal velocity as constant when they most decidedly shouldn't: https://gravityloss.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/powered-landing-analytical-solution/. They don't show the integration in detail, but if you do it yourself, you'll see they assume the terminal velocity is independent of time. Not true. Not even close. The calculation turns out very nice, but the result is just not right.

Comment: So in that link I just gave, the author tries to work out the total impulse required to slow the rocket down from terminal velocity to zero. Eqs 7--9. And tip of the hat to the author, because this isn't something most people bother thinking about and writing on, but with the drag coefficient and air density varying as much as they do in that stage of the flight, it's not even approximately correct to treat terminal velocity as constant---not when you're integrating with respect to time.

Comment: And I mean, this is something I still haven't figured out myself, so it's not like I know any better how to do a powered landing. I just know you can't treat terminal velocity as constant when the rocket is transonic and with 3 km more to go and you're integrating with respect to time.

Comment: Terminal velocity is a weak approximation there, but that's because rocket thrust has entered the picture, not because terminal velocity is changing too fast. How much is his analytic answer off by if you do the simulation?

Comment: Yeah thrust acceleration will vary quite a bit too throughout the burn. But the change in thrust acceleration is on par with the change in air density and drag coefficient, and therefore also with terminal velocity. Neither thrust acceleration nor terminal velocity should be treated as constant there.

Comment: No what am I saying. I’m botching things here. The author clearly says acceleration is assumed to be constant ( which would be done by throttling). So the acceleration term in the integral is perfectly fine. And his terminal velocity term in the integral limit is just the starting velocity at the beginning of the burn—it’s just that he realized that would probably be the terminal velocity, whatever it’s value at the time of ignition. The terminal velocity in the integral itself does vary with drag coefficient and air density but the dependence is with the square root of those parameters...

Comment: So the expression there seems OK so long as you accept the error in assuming a constant drag coefficient and air density (which can be substantial but just not as severe as I first thought).

Comment: OK people I’ll show myself out.